# How do I create a new view in a .xib file without the phone outline?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, interface-builder

I'm trying to design a simple UIView that holds 2 buttons and a label. When I create a new view and set the class to `CartButton` which in its associated `.swift` file is a subclass of `UIView`, it gives me this:

[image]

I don't need the full phone view, I just need a small rectangle. How do I make that happen? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in the Attributes Inspector, Change Size from Inferred to Freeform

[image]

**Or**, if you don't want to publish the change to Git-repository; the top menu should have:

```
Editor -> Canvas -> Show Device Bezels
```

Un-check it.